# CSS/HTML Shrink Navbar Logo slowly

Tags: html, css, navbar

I am currently using this code to shrink the navbar logo of my homepage https://ragnarokeurope.net/ . If you scroll down, you see it shrink super fast. Is there not a way to make it shrink smooth and slowly? like here for example https://www.novaragnarok.com/

```
    <script>
window.onscroll = function() {
  growShrinkLogo()
};

function growShrinkLogo() {
  var Logo = document.getElementById("Logo")
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 5 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 5) {
    Logo.style.width = '30px';
  } else {
    Logo.style.width = '60px';
  }
}
</script>
```

and this is my navbar CSS

```
.navbar-custom .navbar-brand.logo-image img {
    width: 193px;
    height: 75px;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6HFpw5fcaD8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the rule `transition: 1s;` y to the `.navbar-custom .navbar-brand.logo-image img` selector and you will get the desired result. I indicated one second - `1s`. You can set any value that you need yourself.

```
.navbar-custom .navbar-brand.logo-image img {
    width: 193px;
    height: 75px;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;

    transition: 1s; /*add this it*/
}
```

Comment: Hello thanks, this worked. I sadly Cant upvote you just yet, because Im a new user and need more reputation.

Comment: @D A, no problem. glad to help

Answer (score 1):

you can use **transition** property css

```
#Logo {
  transition: width 1.5s;
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition

Comment: Hello thanks, this worked. I sadly Cant upvote you just yet, because Im a new user and need more reputation.